# Is Hazelcast IMap thread safe?

Tags: hazelcast

I want to avoid duplicate key in my Hazelcast, so I am planning to use putIfAbsent. But before I perform the test, I would like to know is IMap still thread safe if my application is hosted on two servers? For example, I have my application hosted on two servers and assume both applications receive the same key and both try to use putIfAbsent to insert.

Comment: [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) is  protocol, not a software. So it does not make sense of asking if it is (or not) thread safe. An IMAP client library might (or not) be thread safe (dive into its documentation)

Comment: sorry, I am asking for hazelcast Imap :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is thread-safe - see http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#locking-maps or http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html

If you do `putIfAbsent("hello","world")` from any two places, at most one will succeed.

Any two places could be two threads in the same JVM, two threads in two JVMs, whatewver.

You don't need to do any kind of locking to ensure this, it's handled for you.